# Date from string is returning nil for "h:mm a"

Tags: ios, swift, date, datetime, datepicker

I just need a time picker in my, so using date picker and setting it to time mode. I wish to set the time on it programmatically and wrote the code below. However, dateFormatter.date returns nil for a valid string and I can't understand why.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = (isDeviceTimeFormat24Hours ? "HH:mm" : "hh:mm aa")
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "17:00")
timePicker.date = date!
timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.time
```

Why would my 'date' object be nil in this case?

Edit: If I set my device time format to 24 hours, then this works fine. But if it is 12 hours, then it doesn't. So something is wrong with "hh:mm aa". After googling, I also tried "h:mm a", still didn't work for me.

Comment: You just need to set your DateFormatter's locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`

Comment: use this dateformatter extension

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

extension DateFormatter {
    
    func changeFormate(isTweleveHours:Bool = true) {
        
        if(isTweleveHours){
            let twelveHourLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            self.locale = twelveHourLocale
            
        } else{
            
            let twentyFourHourLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
            self.locale = twentyFourHourLocale
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////